# Service Account throws an insufficient permission error even it has 'owner' privileges

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

In *Google Cloud Platform* I created a **SERVICE ACCOUNT** and assigned the **OWNER** and **SERVICE ACCOUNT ACTOR** role.

When I run command below

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials travis-test --zone us-central1-c --project phantom-zone-00001
```

it returns error below

> Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
>   ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required “container.clusters.get”
>   permission for “projects/phantom-zone-00001/zones/us-central1-c/clusters/travis-test”.

If I call the command with my own account *(instead of SERVICE ACCOUNT)* it runs perfectly fine

Would you please put me into the right direction?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like issue was related to the part that I didn't revoke it from my local environment when I re-create the account with same name/email.

to revoke

```
gcloud auth revoke service@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

to activate

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account service@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file "C:\Users\user\Downloads\key.json"
```

then it won't give that permission error.