# How do I entitle serviceAccounts via gcloud command-line for Kubernetes API access?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to automate creation of service accounts for use with GKE via the `gcloud` command-line tool. I've figured out a flow that appears to mirror the process used by the Google Cloud Console, but my users don't see to receive the appropriate access.

Here's the commands I'm executing in order:

```
# Environment:
# - uname=<username>
# - email=<user's email address>
# - GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID=<project identifier>
# - serviceAccount="${uname}@${GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
$ gcloud iam service-accounts \
    create "${uname}" --display-name "email:${email}" --format json
$ gcloud projects \
    add-iam-policy-binding "${GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID}" \
        --member "serviceAccount:${serviceAccount}" \
        --role=roles/container.developer --format=json
$ gcloud iam service-accounts keys \
    create "${GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID}-${uname}.json" \
        --iam-account="${serviceAccount}"
```

When this executes, it creates a new service account and generates a key file locally. I then try to use this key to get credentials for my Kubernetes cluster.

```
$ gcloud config configurations create devcluster --activate
$ gcloud config set project devnet-166017
$ gcloud config set compute/zone us-central1-b
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account \
    --key-file="${GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID}-${uname}.json"
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials devcluster
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: \
    code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission for \
    "projects/${GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID}/zones/us-central1-b/clusters/devcluster".
```

It appears that for some reason my service account doesn't have one of the permissions it needs to get credentials, but based on what I've read and what I've observed in the Console, I believe this permission should be part of the `roles/container.developer` role.

Thanks!

Comment: Any solution for this? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556739/service-account-throws-an-insufficient-permission-error-even-it-has-owner-priv) with not luck

Comment: Sort of: I figured out that if I started w/a highly entitled user (a project `Owner` in Google Cloud), the above steps created a service account that had access to do what I needed. However, when I used another service account that had more fine grained set of entitlements, it would fail. It seems like there may be some derived authorizations, but I haven't nailed down exactly what those are.

Comment: I actually ended up just removing the failing `gcloud container clusters get-credentials devcluster` line.
Have **no idea** why it works now, but that's my solution.

Comment: I put in False this attribute and works **gcloud config set container/use_client_certificate False**

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62957050) addresses a different error message with same solution as @HaroldCastillo comment above: `gcloud config set container/use_client_certificate False`.  Seems to affect more recently created (or re-created) GKE clusters, since some point in 2019/2020.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume by service account, you mean the Service Account for Google Cloud. Here are the IAM roles related to GKE: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/iam-integration (search for `container.`).

First create a service account:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create --display-name "GKE cluster access" gke-test
```

Then create a key:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json --iam-account=gke-test@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Now you need to assign some roles to this service account, your options are:

- `roles/container.admin`   Full management of Container Clusters and their Kubernetes API objects.
- `roles/container.clusterAdmin`    Management of Container Clusters.
- `roles/container.developer`   Full access to Kubernetes API objects inside Container Clusters.
- `roles/container.viewer`  Read-only access to Container Engine resources.

Again look at https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/iam-integration page for details.

I assign `roles/container.viewer` (a read-only role, minimum you can assign to get-credentials) to this service account:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT_ID] --role=roles/container.viewer --member=serviceAccount:gke-test@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Logout on gcloud from your current account:

```
gcloud auth revoke
```

Login to gcloud with the service account key:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json
```

Try `get-credentials`:

```
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials test --zone us-west1-a
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for test.
```

It works. I tried it with `roles/container.developer`, which also works.

You can try other permissions and see what works and what doesn't, although you made it clear that the documentation doesn't make it clear which roles have access to `container.clusters.getCredentials`.

Comment: Thanks Ahmet. I'll try to take time to circle around and attempt this again. Not sure if you saw my comment above, re: this works for me when I'm using an account (or serviceAccount) with `roles/owner` versus a more restricted account. I'm not sure why this matters, but I had to give my serviceAccount that executed this process off our automation pipeline higher privileges for the created serviceAccounts to work as expected.

Comment: @ahmet-alp-balkan What additional scopes do you need in order to be able to do `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` using a service account that belongs to another project?