# Why do I get "get-credentials requires edit permission" error in gcloud on my terminal, when it succeeds in Cloud Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

From my laptop, I am able to execute most `gcloud` commands, for example creating a cluster and many other commands. I have the Project Owner role.

But when I try to get credentials for a K8s cluster, I get a permission error. But in Cloud Shell, the command succeeds.

The logged-in account is the same in both.

```
% gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-first-cluster-1 --zone us-central1-c --project my-project
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) get-credentials requires edit permission on my-project
$ gcloud config list account --format "value(core.account)"
<MY EMAIL>
```

But in Cloud Shell, this succeeds!

```
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-first-cluster-1 --zone us-central1-c --project my-project
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for my-first-cluster-1.
$ gcloud config list account --format "value(core.account)"
<MY EMAIL>
```

Comment: It is curious. I wonder whether the error that's being reported is the actual error? Can you try the commands with `--log-http` to see whether there's an obvious discrepancy in the underlying request? Is that a typo or does the error really say "requires edit permission"? I would expect it to say "editor permission"? If nothing else, another bug.

Comment: Are both `gcloud` versions the same?

Comment: I found [this public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156966364) you created a couple of months ago. Can you confirm that `gcloud config get-value container/use_client_certificate` returns the same value in both environments?

Comment: @LundinCast Thank you, that's it! It seems that I see so many bugs that I forget them.

Please add an answer so I can Accept it and have a reference for future users.

Comment: @Joshua Fox, I'm glad it helped. I've written an answer as you suggested. I also took the liberty to edit your question's title adding the actual error message so it's also easier to find.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message is indeed incorrect and not very helpful in this case. This issue occurs when the gcloud config value `container/use_client_certificate` is set to `True` but no client certificate has been configured (note that client certificate is a legacy authentication method and is [disabled by default](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster#restrict_authn_methods) for clusters created with GKE 1.12 and higher.). Setting it to `False` via the following gcloud command solves this issue:

```
gcloud config set container/use_client_certificate False
```

This config value is set to `False` by default in Cloud Shell, which explains the different behavior you experienced.

Comment: Thank you!  This answer worked on GKE v1.14.10-gke.50 for a newly created 1.14 cluster.  An earlier cluster  (1.14 with earlier gke.xx version) did not give this error.  The `gcloud` version was same in both cases.